# $ \operatorname{diam}(A\cup B)\le \operatorname{diam}A+\operatorname{diam}B+\operatorname{dist}(A,B) $

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I come to know about this problem while reading [What is the best way to define the diameter of the empty subset of a metric space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579373/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-the-diameter-of-the-empty-subset-of-a-metric-spac) .I've already proved this but i wanted to prove $$
\operatorname{diam}(A\cup B)\le \operatorname{diam}A+\operatorname{diam}B+\operatorname{dist}(A,B)
$$ in another way
.But i got stuck in between.

Since ,$A \subseteq A\cup B$ &   $B \subseteq A\cup B \implies $ $\operatorname{diam}{A} \le \operatorname{diam}{(A\cup B)}$ & $\operatorname{diam}{(B)} \le \operatorname{diam}{(A\cup B)} \implies\operatorname{diam}{(A\cup B)} \le \frac{\operatorname{diam}A+\operatorname{diam}B}{2} $.

Assuming that i'm on the right track,i tried to proceed further but not getting any idea.

Comment: Can you explain how you got that $$\text{diam} \left(A\cup B\right) \leq \frac{\text{diam} A + \text{diam} B}{2}$$

Comment: @ArielBereslavsky:I've just added the two inequations.

Comment: Your last inequality is false, take for instance $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: You somehow add them backwards. Check your math again. Suppose that $\text{diam} (A) = \text{diam} (B)$ then

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932579/show-that-operatornamediama-cup-b-le-operatornamediama-operatorname/932592#932592

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta:Thanks for pointing this.Actually,I've read a theorem which states that-If $S$ & $T$ are two subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$,then if $S \subset T$ then $\operatorname{diam}{(S)} \le \operatorname{diam}{(T)}$.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta:From this we can conclude that that the inequality in OP holds if if $A$ & $B$ are subsets of metric space **NOT** of their unions.Thanks for this nice counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, your idea does not work.

For $a,a'\in A$, $b,b'\in B$ we have:
$$ d(a,b)\leq d(a,a')+d(a',b')+d(b',b)\leq {\rm diam}(A)+ d(a',b') + {\rm diam} (B) $$
Now take inf on the RHS over $a'\in A$, $b'\in B$.

Comment: :I also followed the same idea.:-)

Comment: :How can we replace $d(a,b)$ from $\operatorname{diam}{(A \cup B)}$ on the LHS of the inequality?

Comment: After taking inf on the RHS you take sup on the LHS. One small point is still left, namely if both $a,b\in A$ or $a,b\in B$. But for that case the inequality is immediate. Don't know if this is clear enough?

Comment: :I've done!Thanks.